# store.dispatch not updating props when called from outside of class

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

store.js

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import { createLogger } from "redux-logger";

import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import reducers from "../reducers";

const logger = createLogger({
  // ...options
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

 export default () => {

  let store = createStore(persistedReducer, {}, applyMiddleware(thunk, logger));
  let persistor = persistStore(store);
  return { store, persistor };
};
```

PathexploredTab.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert,
  Platform,
  Image
} from "react-native";
import { TabView, SceneMap, TabBar } from "react-native-tab-view";
import { Config } from "@common";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { compose } from "redux";
import { Dropdown } from "react-native-material-dropdown";
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import { ScrollView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { Actions } from "react-native-router-flux";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Feather";
import {
  searchImmipaths,
  isKeepData,
  backToInitialState,
  continueFromPrevious,
  fetchDynamicFacts,
  pathExplorerTutorial
} from "../actions/path.actions";
import { checkConnection } from "../service/checkConnection";
import Loader from "./Loader";
import { colors, normalize, family, Images } from "@common";
import ResponsiveImage from 'react-native-responsive-image';
import { RFValue } from "react-native-responsive-fontsize";
import RNPicker from "rn-modal-picker";
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import UserinfoPopUp from "./../pages/UserinfoPopUp";
import { updateUserDetails, getUserDetails } from "../actions/auth.actions";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";
import { copilot, walkthroughable, CopilotStep } from 'react-native-copilot';
import { StepNumberComponent } from "./../pages/newProfileScreen";
import persist from "./../config/store";
import Reactotron from 'reactotron-react-native'

const WalkthroughableImage = walkthroughable(Image);
const WalkthroughableText = walkthroughable(Text);
const WalkthroughableView = walkthroughable(View);
const WalkthroughableTouch = walkthroughable(TouchableOpacity);
const persistStore = persist();
const TooltipComponent = ({
  isFirstStep,
  isLastStep,
  handleNext,
  handlePrev,
  handleStop,
  labels,
  currentStep,
}) => {
  const handleDiscardTutorial = () => {
      Alert.alert(
          '',
          'are you sure you don’t want a tutorial on how to use the app?',
          [
            {
              text: 'yes',
              onPress: () => {AsyncStorage.setItem('DontShowTutorial', JSON.stringify(true)), handleStop()}
            },
            {
              text: 'Cancel',
              onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
              style: 'cancel'
            },
          ],
          { cancelable: false }
        );
  }
  return (
      <View style={styles.tooltipContainer}>
          <Text testID="stepDescription" style={styles.tooltipText}>{currentStep.text}</Text>
          <View style={[styles.bottomBar]}>
              {
                  !isFirstStep ?
                      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.toolTipButton} onPress={handlePrev}>
                          <Text style={styles.toolTipButtonText}>{'Previous'}</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                      : null
              }
              {
                  !isLastStep ?
                      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.toolTipButton} onPress={handleNext}>
                          <Text style={styles.toolTipButtonText}>{'Next'}</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity> :
                      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.toolTipButton} onPress={handleStop}>
                          <Text style={styles.toolTipButtonText}>{'Finish'}</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
              }
               <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => persistStore.store.dispatch(pathExplorerTutorial('bbv'))}>
                  <Text style={styles.toolTipButtonText}>Go</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleDiscardTutorial}>
                  <Text style={styles.toolTipButtonText}>Do not show tutorial</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
      </View>
  );
}
const window = Dimensions.get("window");
var width = window.width;
var height = window.height;
var immigrationInterst = [];
var countryIntrest = [];
let countryIntrestNow = [];
var FirstRoute = () => <View style={[{ height: height }]} />;

let disableButton = false;
var lastSearchedCountries = [];
var SecondRoute = () => <View style={[{ height: height }]} />;

class PathexploredTab extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.imageMap = ['', Images.studyImage, Images.workImage, Images.residencyImage, Images.tourismImage];
    this.state = {
      isloading: false,
      buttonone: false,
      immibut1: false,
      immibut2: false,
      immibut3: false,
      immibut4: false,
      userInfoPopUpVisible: false, 
      countrybut1: false,
      countrybut2: false,
      countrybut3: false,
      countrybut4: false,
      filedsToShow: [],
      countrybut5: false,
      countrybut6: false,
      selectedval: "Select the Country",
      index: 0,
      routes: [
        { key: "first", title: "Select Goals" },
        { key: "second", title: "Select Countries" }
      ],
      checkconnection: false,
      errorMessage: "",
      isItemSelected: true,
      currentlySelectedItemIndex: -1,
      isItemChecked: true,
      checkboxData: ""
    };
  }
  componentDidUpdate = (nextProps) => {
    Reactotron.log('=====', nextProps.userPressedGo)
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
    

  }
  componentWillMount = async() => {
    const {
      getUser: { userDetails },
      authData: { token }
    } = this.props;
    this.props.dispatch(getUserDetails(userDetails.userid, token))
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
       this.props.start();
    }, 1000);
    immigrationInterst = [];
    countryIntrest = [];
    countryIntrestNow = [];
    const {
      getUser: { userDetails }
    } = this.props;
   
  
  }


  
  callProceed = () => {
     const {
      isItemSelected,
      currentlySelectedItemIndex,
      isItemChecked
    } = this.state;
    if (isItemSelected) {
      Alert.alert("Immigreat", "Please select any goal");
      return;
    }
    const lastGoal = this.props.immigationInterest[0]

    //This is a bit of a hacky fix but it works.
    let allPrevCountriesFound = lastSearchedCountries.every(ai => countryIntrestNow.includes(ai))
      && (lastSearchedCountries.length == countryIntrestNow.length);

    //We want to clear and search when:
    //a) There is no exploration id
    //b) Even if there is an exploration id but the lastGoal or last countries dont match
    //Note: We make one exception for if exploration id exists but the lastSearchedCountries is just an empty list

    let noExplorationId = (this.props.explorationId === "");
    let countryGoalDontMatch = (lastGoal != currentlySelectedItemIndex || !allPrevCountriesFound);
    let isProceedException = (lastSearchedCountries.length == 0 && !noExplorationId);

    noExplorationId || (!noExplorationId && countryGoalDontMatch && !isProceedException)
      ?
      this.clearAndSearch()
      : Alert.alert(
        "Immigreat",
        "Previous exploration found. Would you like to continue?",

        [
          {
            text: "START FROM BEGINNING",
            onPress: () => {
              this.props.dispatch(continueFromPrevious(0));
              this.props.dispatch(backToInitialState());
              this.props.dispatch(isKeepData(false));
              this._searchData();
            },
            style: "cancel"
          },
          {
            text: "CONTINUE",
            onPress: () => {
              lastSearchedCountries = [...countryIntrest];
              this.props.dispatch(isKeepData(true));
              this.props.didTapOnSearch();
            }
          },
          {
            text: "Cancel",
            onPress: () => console.log("Canceled"),
            style: "cancel"
          }
        ],
        { cancelable: false }
      );
  }
 
  
 
  _onPressBackButton = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        isItemSelected: true,
        currentlySelectedItemIndex: -1,
        isItemChecked: false
      },
      () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.intialLoadValues();
          //this.setState({ isItemSelected: true });
        }, 0);
      }
    );
  }

  extraOptionsRefresh() {
    const { currentlySelectedItemIndex, isItemChecked } = this.state;
    this.setState({ isItemChecked: !isItemChecked })
    switch (currentlySelectedItemIndex) {
      case 1:
        this.setState({checkBoxData:
          "Do you want to explore options you may have after your studies?"});
        break;
      case 2:
        this.setState({checkBoxData: 
          "Do you want to explore other goal options (such as studies) that can lead to work options?"});
        break;
      case 3:
        this.setState({checkBoxData:
          "Do you want to explore other goal options (such as studies or work) that could lead to permanent residency in the future?"});
        break;
      case -1:
        this.setState({checkBoxData: ""});
        break;
    }
  }

  intialLoadValues() {
    const { currentlySelectedItemIndex, isItemChecked } = this.state;
    /*var checkBoxData = "";
    switch (currentlySelectedItemIndex) {
      case 1:
        checkBoxData =
          "Do you want to explore options you may have after your studies?";
        break;
      case 2:
        checkBoxData = "Do you want to explore other goal options (such as studies) that can lead to work options?";
        break;
      case 3:
        checkBoxData =
          "Do you want to explore other goal options (such as studies or work) that could lead to permanent residency in the future?";
        break;
      case 4:
        checkBoxData = "";
        break;
    }*/

    FirstRoute = () => (
      <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white" }}>
        <Animatable.View animation="fadeIn" duration={1200} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "#DBDDDF",
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
              flex: 1
            }}
          >
            <View style={{ padding: 20 }}>
              <Text
                style={{
                  textAlign: "center",
                  fontFamily: "SourceSansPro-Semibold",
                  color: "#2C393F",
                  fontSize: RFValue(12)
                }}
              >
                Select the Immigration goal that you would be interested in
                exploring
              </Text>
              <Text
                style={{
                  textAlign: "center",
                  color: "#008BC7",
                  fontFamily: "SourceSansPro-Regular",
                  fontSize: RFValue(10)
                }}
              >
                You can select/deselect ONLY one goal at a time by clicking the buttons. This is so we can help you hone your search!
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>

          {(this.state.isItemSelected && this.state.currentlySelectedItemIndex < 0) ? (
            <View style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>
             {/*<Animatable.View animation="fadeIn" duration={1200} style={{ flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row' }}>*/}
              <View style={styles.custombuttonView}>
                <View style={{ width: "50%" }}>
                <CopilotStep text="Select Your goals" order={1} name="study">
                  <WalkthroughableTouch
                    testID={`${Config.immigerat[0].code + 'button'}`}
                    onPress={() =>
                      this._immigreateIntrest(Config.immigerat[0].code)
                    }
                    style={
                      this.state.immibut1
                        ? styles.selectedbutton
                        : styles.buttonstyleview
                    }
                  >
                    <WalkthroughableText
                      style={
                        this.state.immibut1
                          ? styles.selectedbuttontext
                          : styles.buttonstyletext
                      }
                    >
                      {Config.immigerat[0].value}
                    </WalkthroughableText>
                  </WalkthroughableTouch>
                  </CopilotStep>
                </View>
                <View style={{ width: "50%" }}>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    testID={`${Config.immigerat[1].code + 'button'}`}
                    onPress={() =>
                      this._immigreateIntrest(Config.immigerat[1].code)
                    }
                    style={
                      this.state.immibut2
                        ? styles.selectedbutton
                        : styles.buttonstyleview
                    }
                  >
                    <Text
                      style={
                        this.state.immibut2
                          ? styles.selectedbuttontext
                          : styles.buttonstyletext
                      }
                    >
                      {Config.immigerat[1].value}
                    </Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.custombuttonView}>
                <View style={{ width: "50%" }}>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    testID={`${Config.immigerat[2].code + 'button'}`}
                    onPress={() =>
                      this._immigreateIntrest(Config.immigerat[2].code)
                    }
                    style={
                      this.state.immibut3
                        ? styles.selectedbutton
                        : styles.buttonstyleview
                    }
                  >
                    <Text
                      style={
                        this.state.immibut3
                          ? styles.selectedbuttontext
                          : styles.buttonstyletext
                      }
                    >
                      {Config.immigerat[2].value}
                    </Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <View style={{ width: "50%" }}>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    testID={`${Config.immigerat[3].code + 'button'}`}
                    onPress={() =>
                      this._immigreateIntrest(Config.immigerat[3].code)
                    }
                    style={
                      this.state.immibut4
                        ? styles.selectedbutton
                        : styles.buttonstyleview
                    }
                  >
                    <Text
                      style={
                        this.state.immibut4
                          ? styles.selectedbuttontext
                          : styles.buttonstyletext
                      }
                    >
                      {Config.immigerat[3].value}
                    </Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </View>
              {/*</Animatable.View>*/}
            </View>
          ) : (
              <View style={{ flex: 0.75, marginTop: 30 }}>
              {/*<Animatable.View animation="fadeIn" duration={1200}>*/}
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignContent: 'center' }}>
                  <TouchableOpacity testID='goBackButton'
                    onPress={this._onPressBackButton} style={{ padding: 10 }} >
                    <View style={{ width: 80 }}>
                      <Icon name="chevron-left" size={30} color="black" />
                    </View>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  {<TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => this._immigreateIntrest("null")}
                    style={[styles.selectedbutton, { width: "50%" }]}
                  >
                     <Text style={styles.selectedbuttontext}>
                      {Config.immigerat[this.state.currentlySelectedItemIndex - 1].value}
                    </Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>}
                </View>
                {currentlySelectedItemIndex !== 4 && (
                  <View
                    style={{
                      borderWidth: 1,
                      borderRadius: 3,
                      borderColor: "rgba(110,110,110,0.4)",
                      flex: 1,
                      marginHorizontal: 10,
                      marginTop: 30,
                      flexDirection: "row"
                    }}
                  >
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      activeOpacity={0.8}
                      onPress={() => {
                          this.extraOptionsRefresh()
                        //setTimeout(() => {
                          //this.extraOptionsRefresh();
                          //this.intialLoadValues();
                          //this.setState({ isItemChecked: !isItemChecked });
                          //}, 100);
                        }
                      }
                      style={{
                        // flex: 0.35,
                        alignItems: "center",
                        justifyContent: "center",
                        marginLeft: 15
                      }}
                      hitSlop={{ top: 20, bottom: 20, left: 50, right: 50 }}
                    >
                      <View
                        style={[
                          styles.button,
                          {
                            backgroundColor: "white",
                            borderColor: "rgba(110,110,110,0.4)",
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            borderRadius: 2,
                            width: 20,
                            height: 20
                          }
                        ]}
                      >
                        {this.state.isItemChecked ? (
                          <Icon name={"check"} color={colors.LIGHT_BLUE} size={15} />
                        ) : null}
                      </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        marginVertical: 10,
                        marginLeft: 10,
                        fontFamily: "SourceSansPro-Bold",
                        color: "#242424",
                        fontSize: RFValue(12)
                      }}
                    >
                      {this.state.checkBoxData}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                )}
                {(!this.state.isItemSelected && this.state.currentlySelectedItemIndex > 0) &&
                  <Animatable.View animation="fadeIn" duration={1200} style={{ flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                    <ResponsiveImage source={this.imageMap[this.state.currentlySelectedItemIndex]} initWidth="270" initHeight="220" />
                  </Animatable.View>
                }
              </View>
            )}
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              testID='searchButton'
              onPress={() => !disableButton && this.showAlert1()}
              style={{
                width: 130,
                justifyContent: "center",
                backgroundColor: colors.LIGHT_BLUE,
                borderRadius: 100,
                padding: 10,
                alignSelf: "center",
                marginTop: height > 700 ? 60 : 40,
                marginBottom: 20
              }}
            >
              <Text
                style={{
                  textAlign: "center",
                  color: "#fff",
                  fontFamily: "SourceSansPro-Regular"
                }}
              >
                Search
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </Animatable.View>
      </ScrollView>
    );

    SecondRoute = () => (
      <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white" }}>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
          <View
            style={{
              alignSelf: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
              width: width
            }}
          >
            <View style={{ margin: 20, alignSelf: "center" }}>
              <Text
                style={{
                  textAlign: "center",
                  fontFamily: "SourceSansPro-Semibold",
                  color: "#2C393F",
                  fontSize: 15
                }}
              >
                Select all countries you are keen to explore
              </Text>
              <Text
                style={{
                  textAlign: "center",
                  color: "rgba(44, 57, 63,0.6)",
                  marginTop: 20,
                  fontFamily: "SourceSansPro-Semibold"
                }}
              >
                From:
              </Text>
              <View style={styles.loginView}>
                <Field
                  name="selectcountry"
                  placeholder={this.state.selectedval}
                  component={this.renderDropdown}
                  data={Config.countries}
                />
              </View>
              <Text
                style={{
                  textAlign: "center",
                  color: "rgba(44, 57, 63,0.6)",
                  marginTop: 20,
                  fontFamily: "SourceSansPro-Semibold"
                }}
              >
                To:
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View>
            <View style={styles.custombuttonView}>
              <View style={{ width: "33%" }}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  testID={`${Config.intrestcountry[0].value + 'interestButton'}`}
                  onPress={() =>
                    this._countryIntrest(Config.intrestcountry[0].code)
                  }
                >
                  <Image
                    style={styles.countryIcon}
                    source={this.state.countrybut1
                      ? Images.usa_selected
                      : Images.usa_unavailable}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              <View style={{ width: "33%" }}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  testID={`${Config.intrestcountry[1].value + 'interestButton'}`}
                 
                >
                  <Image
                    style={styles.countryIcon}
                    source={this.state.countrybut2
                      ? Images.canada_selected
                      : Images.canada_unavailable}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              <View style={{ width: "33%" }}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  testID={`${Config.intrestcountry[2].value + 'interestButton'}`}
                  onPress={() =>
                    this._countryIntrest(Config.intrestcountry[2].code)
                  }
                >
                  <Image
                  
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.custombuttonView}>
              <View style={{ width: "33%" }}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  testID={`${Config.intrestcountry[3].value + 'interestButton'}`}
                  onPress={() =>
                    this._countryIntrest(Config.intrestcountry[3].code)
                  }
                >
                  <Image
                   
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              <View style={{ width: "33%" }}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  testID={`${Config.intrestcountry[4].value + 'interestButton'}`}
                  onPress={() =>
                    this._countryIntrest(Config.intrestcountry[4].code)
                  }
                >
                  <Image
                    
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              <View style={{ width: "33%" }}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  testID={`${Config.intrestcountry[5].value + 'interestButton'}`}
                  onPress={() =>
                    this._countryIntrest(Config.intrestcountry[5].code)
                  }
                >
                  <Image
                   
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              testID='countrySearchButton'
              onPress={() => !disableButton && this.showAlert1()}
              style={{
              
              }}
            >
              <Text
               
              >
                Search
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
  _countryIntrest(code) {
    // alert(code);
    var index = countryIntrest.indexOf(code);
    var butstr = "countrybut" + code;
    if (index == -1) {
      countryIntrest.push(code);
      countryIntrestNow.push(code);
      this.setState({ [butstr]: true });
      this.intialLoadValues();
    } else {
      countryIntrest.splice(index, 1);
      countryIntrestNow.splice(index, 1);
      this.setState({ [butstr]: false });
      this.intialLoadValues();
    }
  }

  _immigreateIntrest = async(code) => {
    if(code === 4){
      )
      return;
    }
    const { isItemSelected } = this.state;
    if (code === "null") {
     
      
      );
    } else {
      await this.setState(
       
      );
    }
  }
  renderScene = ({ route }) => {
    switch (route.key) {
      case 'first':
       
      case 'second':
       
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {this.props.isLoading && (
          <View
            style={{
             
            }}
          >
            <Loader />
          </View>
        )}
        <TabView
          removeClippedSubviews={Platform.OS === "android" ? true : false}
          style={{
            backgroundColor: this.state.index === 0 ? "#DBDDDF" : "white"
          }}
          navigationState={this.state}
          removeClippedSubviews={Platform.OS === "android" ? true : false}
          renderTabBar={props => (
            <TabBar
             
              }}
             
             
              pass
              getLabelText={({ route }) => route.title}
            />
          )}
        />
        <UserinfoPopUp
          visible={this.state.userInfoPopUpVisible}
          onClose={()=>this.setState({ userInfoPopUpVisible: false })}
          userPopUpSubmit={this._userPopUpSubmit.bind(this)}
          />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

mapStateToProps = state => ({
  userPressedGo: state.pathReducer.getImmipathDetails.userPressedGo,
});

mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  dispatch
});

export default compose(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  ),
  reduxForm({
    form: "pathexplorertab"
    // validate
  })
)(copilot({
  tooltipComponent: TooltipComponent,
  stepNumberComponent: StepNumberComponent
})(PathexploredTab));
```

Pathexplorer.js contains Pathexplorer class in which there is an component called ToolTipComponent from which i am calling an action but the action isn't reflected in mapStateToProps. The reason i am forced to do this is that i am using a library called react-native-copilot in which i have a custom tooltip component from which i want to access the state

Comment: `this is how i am trying to call an action` where ?

Comment: @b3hr4d so in abc.js outside class component. in ```TooltipComponent```

Comment: Try this `onPress={()=>store.dispatch(action)}`

Comment: So, basically from the functional component `TooltipComponent`? Why are you trying to dispatch directly from the store immediately when the component mounts?

Comment: @b3hr4d ya did the exact thing the action and reducers are called but the props is updating i what to access the prop in ```componentWillReceiveProps```

Comment: inside Abc?Share full abc

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` for all practical purposes is deprecated. Please share your full, relevant code. Though any other component should be irrelevant to `TooltipComponent`.

Comment: @b3hr4d ABC is just an example the full code is very large so basically i want to call action from outside call which will update some props and use that in my Class

Comment: @DrewReese ok also tried with componentDidUpdate

Comment: Tried what? What are you trying to access? Please share all relevant code. You've the `onPress` issue already pointed out, but it sounds like you're asking about more than that.

Comment: Share props and specified function then!

Comment: @b3hr4d updated the above code

Comment: @b3hr4d ```persistStore.store.dispatch(pathExplorerTutorial('bbv'))``` this is the call to action

Comment: `userPressedGo` didnt update your component?

Comment: Did `pathExplorerTutorial('bbv')` action change `userPressedGo` data ?

Comment: @b3hr4d it did but not accessible in my pathexplorer class in the reducer in can see that change

Comment: Did you return updated changes? share your reducer as well, btw your main question did get the answer, doesn't change your main question maybe someone in the future had this quest.

Comment: @b3hr4d yes i did returned updated changes. If i call the same action frm within the class then i am able to get the updated prop in ```componentWillReceiveProps```

Comment: So use connected components should solve the problem, check the last part of my answer.

Comment: Or since `TooltipComponent` is a functional component use the `useDispatch` hook and dispatch the action in the `onPress` handler. Save the `connect` HOC usage and decorating.

Comment: @DrewReese thanks man useDispatch() did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem in this event:

```
onPress={store.dispatch(action)}
```

should be:

```
onPress={()=>store.dispatch(action)}
```

By the way you can connect your functional component like class component:

```
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )
)(TooltipComponent)
```